# Examination software

Tags: security, document-management

We currently use [ExamSoft](http://learn.examsoft.com/) to conduct examinations. It is great but sometimes we have examinations that are open book (PDF, PPT) or need Excel. Is there any software that would help me do this in a secure way?
Nonsecure mode in Examsoft lets you communicate through airdrop, bluetooth, or even WiFi hotspots. If there is any additional freeware that can be managed from a server side, this would also would do. For ex. a program that randomly takes screenshots and zips and uploads it to the local server or an application that makes a sound (even if it's muted) if bluetooth or wifi is switched on (We have exam supervisors). Or an app that restricts to 2 or 3 applications. Any other ideas or software or any suggestion that could reduce the level of cheating?

Examsoft is a software that lets you conduct examination in their laptop. It has two modes - Secure and Nonsecure. In secure mode the application goes into a full screen and disables access to any other application. Problem is when we have exams that is open book or requires excel where we administer nonsecure mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "open boo"? What are your other requirements? Please explain like nobody knew what ExamSoft is. Is it for exams in a single room, or remote?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Obviously, an open-boo exam is one where students are permitted to jump-scare each other during the exam. They're pretty common in universities affiliated with haunted houses.

Comment: @Kodiologist Thats hilarious. What I mean was open book examination where the students are allowed to use other textbooks (PDF, Physical copy), or PPT files.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I have edited to expain what examsoft is. Thanks to jan- doggen for the edits and hyperlink.